# quasi isomorphism of two dg algebras

Tags: homological-algebra, differential-graded-algebras

I want to construct a chain of morphisms from a dg algebra $A$ to $B$. I assume that $A$ and $B$ is non positive, i.e, $A^n$ vanishes for $n$ greater than zero. What I have is that $H^*(A)$ is isomorphic to $H^*(B)$ as a graded algebra. Here $H^*(A)$ is the graded homology algebra associated with $A$. Now the Kadeishvili Theorem show that we have $H^*(A)\rightarrow A$ and $H^*(B)\rightarrow B$ are quasi-isomorphism of $A_{\infty}-$algebras.  Can I deduce that $H^*(A)\rightarrow H^*(B)$ is a morphism of $A_{\infty}-$algebras?

Added after edit: Now suppose that we have an equivalence of categories $\mathcal D(A)\rightarrow \mathcal D(B)$ which sends A to B. Then is the above question true? We know from [A infinity structure on Ext algebras](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0606144.pdf#page21) that the higher multiplications of $H^*(A) $ are essentially the same with the Massey products. Now the question is whether such an equivalence ‘preserves’ Massey products.

Comment: The problem addressed in the preprint https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0401007.pdf seems to be helpful.

Comment: It is generally not true that A and B are linked by quasi isomorphisms. There are counter examples (though I haven’t checked yet and don’t know a concrete example) where A and B are graded fields.

Comment: For a counterexample to your first question, take $A$ and $B$ to be the rational polynomial de Rham forms on two spaces that have isomorphic cohomology rings; then equip $HA$ and $HB$ with $A_\infty$ structures by Kadeishvili and recall that these can be upgraded to $C_\infty$ structures, which determine the rational homotopy type of the spaces being modelled. The isomorphism $HA \to HB$, if it were a map of $A_\infty$ algebras, would also be a map, furthermore iso, of $C_\infty$ algebras. We would conclude that two spaces with isomorphic cohomology have the same rational hmtpy type (not true)